# What are the consequences of framing Justin Ayo?

Tags: fallout-4

During the mission "Plugging the Leak", once you work out who is helping the synths escape from the Institute he tries to bargain with you and comes up with an alternate plan that involves framing the acting director of the synth retention bureau, Justin Ayo.

What are the consequences of framing Justin Ayo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Justin Ayo will be banished to the surface.  The corsers and Justin will be gone, a new head of synth reclamation will be put into place.  I've not seen any consequences from this action as if yet, just that guy being gone.

Answer (score 3):

If you turn Liam in, I noticed in the dialog with Ayo he said at one point "soon there won't be anything I don't know about" which kind of turned me off to having helped him, but he did give 1k caps reward and honestly can't be having synths escaping can we. :p